# Python filter URL from HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

you would have all guessed: I'm quite new :) Currently into learning python and proceeding well. After quite some theory (learnpythonthehardway.com) and lots of googling and reading i'm trying to get into the topic with my first real world script. Task is to read some values from the web which in this case is protected with an Login form. I already managed to requests to post the login data.

Now problem is that this login doesn't seem to be valid before a JS redirection happened. The response of the first site contains some html beginning with a

```
<script>document.href='/file.php?...stuff...'</script>
```

I tried to search around for regex replacements or other stuff but couldn't find a smart way to filter out the path/url part in there. If i had that i would manually get this page and see if it works and the session still persists afterwards.

As this HTML/JS filtering will be important later to grab my content this is a part i'd really love to do right but i'm stuck.

Hopefully you can help!

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Assuming `s` is storing the contents of this string, what is wrong with a simple `s.split("'")[1]`?

Comment: For HTML document mining, you'd want to use say BeautifulSoup 4 aka `bs4` for parsing the HTML into a DOM tree; then process the each `<script>` element contents separately.

Comment: @barakmanos thanks, for this case split did a good job - could have known that myself.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thanks - i'll look at bs4 closely for my other parsing issues.